# New line when editing text files in ubuntu terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, terminal, newlines

I know that to symbolize a new line, I would do echo -e "line 1 \nline 2" > text.txt.
I find that using \n repeatedly can be annoying, and I would to know if there a way to actually go down a line in the terminal without it executing commands. Like if I were to edit python in the terminal I could write

```
def main():
    print "hello world"
```

And pressing "enter" to go to a new line wouldn't have executed def main(): , it just went to a new line. Is there anything similar to this in the normal terminal?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to echo text as in your example, you can just use the Enter key in place of `\n` like this:

```
echo "line 1
line 2" > text.txt
```

For that to work, you have to surround your text with `""` as shown or with `''`.

If you want to enter a sequence of commands without executing them until you're done, you can begin the sequence with a `{` and end it with a `}`, like this:

```
{
echo line 1
echo line 2
date
}
```

You can also redirect the output of the whole sequence by following the closing `}` with your redirection, as

```
{
echo line 1
echo line 2
date
} > text.txt
```

Comment: I want to be able to do what you did in the first example, but every time I hit enter it executes the command

Comment: @WillumMaguire: If you typed `echo "line 1` with only *one* " and hit Enter, I would expect you to see the secondary prompt `> `. If not that, then an error message about an unterminated string. What exactly are you typing that is executed when you hit Enter?

Comment: I just tried this: echo "line 1 I also tried using E0F, but I can't seem to get it to work correctly

Comment: @WillumMaguire: I'm sorry, but I am unable to explain the behavior you are seeing. I tried a few different shells but always saw one of the two results I mentioned above. I also skimmed the bash(1) man page but did not see any options that would cause that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the unmatched quotation mark, you can use [heredocs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document):

```
$ python <<EOF
> def main():
>       print "Hello"
> 
> main()
> EOF
Hello
$
```

Note that `EOF` is simply a common and convenient delineator, any token will do.